# Is it possible to embed the iphone messaging app into your app?

Tags: ios, ios7

I want user to able to send messages from within my app in an interface similar to the iOS SMS app. Is it possible to embed and possibly customize the sms app into your application?

Comment: You can use the MFMessageComposer for integrating the native message sending interface with your application.

Comment: See [System Messaging Programming Topics for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010404) and [MFMessageComposeViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MFMessageComposeViewController).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you **can send** SMS from your app by using MFMessageComposer. But you **can't receive** sms in IOS like Message app. If you try to do that, apple will reject your app.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.. Try this sample.. Implement this code in your app.

[Message Chat Sample](https://github.com/Tech-Dev-Mobile/IOS-Message-Chat)